# Question "Does HUION K58 work with Ubuntu?" incorrectly marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicates

The question [Does HUION K58 work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545559/does-huion-k58-work-with-ubuntu) was marked as a duplicate of [What hardware does Ubuntu Touch support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-does-ubuntu-touch-support) which is incorrect.

The original question is not asking about Ubuntu Touch, and the Ubuntu Touch answer appears to be regarding "iPad style" tablets anyways (touch screen computing devices), rather than the wacom-style drawing tablets, which are an entirely different class of device.

I believe since the original question explicitly explains what sort of device the Huion k58 is, it did not require editing for clarification (as some guides suggested).

Apologies if this is the wrong avenue to address a duplicate on askubuntu, I'm following point 3 from [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5874/mark-a-marked-as-a-duplicate-question-as-not-duplicate) for addressing incorrect duplicates. I have insufficient rep for points 1 and 4, and have tried 2 with moderate success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, its OK to raise the matter here on Meta.

Those members who have sufficient privilege would then have visibility of your question and can cast a reopen vote.

Additionally/alternatively you could also flag the question for moderator attention.  Explain as you have in a custom flag message and the moderator dealing with your flag can action it accordingly.

Anyway - I agree with you and have reopened the question.